# Postgres foreign key on delete constraint

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

Been following the guide on http://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html trying to get simple foreign keys setup, however, I can't find any info on using `ON CASCADE` or `ON DELETE`.

On http://doc.gorm.io/database.html#migration under the `Add Foreign Key` section it does make use of `ON DELETE` and `ON CASCADE`, however when I use this method when inserting I get a fk constraint error.

I'm looking for advice on using the first method ,`gorm:"foreignkey:UserRefer"`, to also specify `ON DELETE` or `ON CASCADE`. Any suggestions?

EDIT #1:
To show what I mean by error, I'll use this as an example:

**Note.go:**

```
type Note struct {
  NoteId              int       `gorm:"primary_key;AUTO_INCREMENT"`
  RecipientId         int       `gorm:"index"`
  Content             string    `gorm:"not null"`
  CreatedAt           time.Time `gorm:"not null"`
  UpdatedAt           time.Time `gorm:"not null"`
}
```

**User.go**

```
type User struct {
  UserId              int       `gorm:"primary_key;AUTO_INCREMENT"`
  Username            string    `gorm:"not null;unique"`
  Email               string    `gorm:"not null;unique"`
  Notes               []Note
  CreatedAt           time.Time `gorm:"not null"`
  UpdatedAt           time.Time `gorm:"not null"`
}
```

**database.go**

```
db.AutoMigrate(&models.User{}, &models.Note{})
db.Model(&models.Note{}).AddForeignKey("recipient_id", "users(user_id)", "RESTRICT", "RESTRICT")

user := models.User{Username:"test", Email:"test@gmail.com"}
note := models.Note{RecipientId:user.UserId, Content:"test"}

db.Create(&user)
db.Create(&note)
```

When the above code is placed in its proper functions, this error is thrown:

```
(pq: insert or update on table "notes" violates foreign key constraint "notes_recipient_id_users_user_id_foreign")
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue too.
The good idea is set a foreign keys when declare struct in your case is:

```
type Note struct {
  NoteId              int       `gorm:"primary_key;AUTO_INCREMENT"`
  RecipientId         int       `gorm:"recipient_id"`// your variant `gorm:"index"`
  Content             string    `gorm:"not null"`
  CreatedAt           time.Time `gorm:"not null"`
  UpdatedAt           time.Time `gorm:"not null"`
}

type User struct {
  UserId              int       `gorm:"primary_key;AUTO_INCREMENT"`
  Username            string    `gorm:"not null;unique"`
  Email               string    `gorm:"not null;unique"`
  Notes               []Note    `gorm:"foreignkey:recipient_id"`
  CreatedAt           time.Time `gorm:"not null"`
  UpdatedAt           time.Time `gorm:"not null"`
}
```

Also in the future, if you will delete or update  related records folow this [Golang Gorm: Is it possible to delete a record via a many2many relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38270156/golang-gorm-is-it-possible-to-delete-a-record-via-a-many2many-relationship)